# PHP script showing HTML inside JSON

Tags: php, json

I have created a PHP scipt to test some external system that is returning a JSON string. But there is HTML inside the JSON. I have tried setting a header but it ain't working.

Here is my code.

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo "{\"CarName\":\"Audi\",\"CarPrice\": \"100000USD\"}";
```

Comment: Have you tried using json_encode?

Comment: `echo json_encode(['CarName' => 'Audi', 'CarPrice' => '100000USD']); exit;` The `exit` takes care of any HTML that might proceed this code. If the HTML is before this code, then you need to look at how your app produces content.

Comment: Don't know if it is relevant. But have you tried Content-Type with a capital "T" ?

Comment: @jobou HTTP header names are case-insensitive

Comment: http://cherrytestsite.host22.com/ is the url for the code.. Hope that helps. 
probably html is due to hosting?

Comment: @susanoochidori find a better host; one that doesn't inject tracking tags into your content

Comment: anyone knows of any free hosting that doesnt inject tracking tags?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. Get a better web host

Answer (score 0):

You can *try* and tell the browser to ignore the tracking injected code, but there's no guarantee your hosting isn't rewriting that header also, by manipulating `Content-Length`:

```
$payload = json_encode( YOUR_ARRAY );

Header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8");
Header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($payload));
die($payload);
```

The solution, however, is either to get a different hosting or to contact them (there's all sorts of hosted frameworks that **NEED** proper JSON sent by PHP: is *none* of them working there? I find that difficult to believe) and ask how to *not* get injected trackers.